# Connection was reset when migrated jomsocial to the latest Version

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I've upgraded my old joomla version 1.5.26 website to Joomla version 2.5.8 version successfully. It also upgraded my jomsocial tables in the database. After that, i have downloaded the jomsocial extensions version 2.8.0 and installed it in my joomla website. I also assigned the jomscoial "home front end page" to my menu and whenever i tried to open it then it is showing me the connection was reset. All other jomsocial functions are working properly except the homepage of jomscoial alias the front page of the jomsocial extension.

Does anyone knows how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the bug is related to long URL's in the title field of the activity stream.  It has been reported to JomSocial by several (including me).  I haven't seen a fix yet.  I'll post one when it is offered.  It's affecting my site too.

Comment: Hmmm okays, so till now there is no solutions for it?